# Is it possible to use JFS on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, jfs

I have some TS-7800 boards that run BusyBox/Debian from SD cards.  Two of the partitions on the SD cards use JFS.  I create and edit the SD cards on a CentOS computer.

A while back I upgraded to CentOS 7.  Apparently this caused me to lose all JFS support.

I tried to enable it using the same procedure I used to enable it on CentOS 6:

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/CentOSPlus

Even though the procedure claims to work for CentOS 7, I cannot find a jfsutils package.  I have spent many hours on Google and have searched all of the CentOS repos I can find but it appears that there is no jfsutils package for CentOS 7.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Am I out of luck?

Comment: It's not there. It doesn't appear in the centos 7 extras packages. It is present in the centos 6 extras packages. If it's not there, then you can try downloading the source from centos 6 and building an rpm for it (if you want it for regular system use), or just download and build the jfsutils source yourself - it's on sourceforge

Comment: I appreciate the help @Petesh  I was able to compile and install the jfsutils package from the source code found on sourceforge.  I can now create JFS filesystems on the SD card.  This is the most important half of my issue.  The other half is mounting JFS which I apparently cannot do without the kmod-jfs package.  Unlike the jfsutils package, I cannot find the source to the kmod-jfs package anywhere.  ...and of course it is not in any of the CentOS 7 repos.  I can live without it if I have to but I'm hoping that someone may have a suggestion as to how to fix this issue.

Comment: I contacted Elrepo and requested that they add the kmod-jfs package to the el7 repo.  They were also nice enough to submit a request to CentOS for the jfsutils package.  In the meantime, I'm using the CentOS Plus kernel and it seems to be working fine with JFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You have to use the CentOSPlus kernel though.